# Java Card Crypto Exception RSA Key Encryption

Tags: java, encryption, key, javacard

I'm trying to recreate a public key at a Java Card and use it to encrypt some data.

Here is the code to build the public key that I'm using:

```
rsaPublicId = (RSAPublicKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_RSA_PUBLIC, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_2048, false);
rsaPublicId.setExponent(rsaExponent, (short) 0, (short) rsaExponent.length);
rsaPublicId.setModulus(rsaPublicModulus, (short) 12, (short) ((short) rsaPublicModulus.length - (short) 12));

cipherId.init(rsaPublicId, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
```

And When I try to encrypt a data I use this code:

```
cipherId.doFinal(serviceBytes, (short) 0, (short) 16, buffer, (short) 0);
```

But it occurs a javacard.security.cryptoException with the detail message of "null"

```
cipherId = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_RSA_PKCS1, false);
```

The modulus is set with the size of 308, it's created with Java and sent to the card.

Comment: Surround your exception with a try-catch block and tell us what is the result of getReason() called on the exception instance, please.

Comment: In the Exception the code 5 appears. 

It says "
/*** This reason code is used to indicate that the signature or cipher algorithm does not pad the incoming message and the input message is not block aligned. */

    public static final short ILLEGAL_USE = 5;"

Comment: What detail message? There is no such thing as a detail message in Java Card Classic. I mean: strings are not even supported....

Comment: You can see a message with debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your modulus should be the exact same size set during the `buildKey` call. So if your size is 308 (308 *what*?) then your key is either too small (in bits) or too big (if it was specified in bytes).

It is a subject of discussion if smaller keys (up to a certain minimum, 308 bits is too small) should be allowed. In the current specification however it is not allowed to use smaller keys than the one given in the method call; the keys - and thus the modulus - needs to be the exact size specified.

Comment: Which Java Card implementation are you using? You would expect a too large or too small a modulus to be detected earlier; it seems the implementation is not fail fast.

Comment: I'm generating a RSA Key Pair at a Java application and sending the modulus of the public key to the Applet. Then I would like to rebuild this key and using it to criptography some data and send it back. 

The modulus length is 617 string - 308 bytes.

I'm using the 2.2 Java Card.

Comment: So create a public key of size 2464 bits (which is the number of bits of a 308 byte key). You don't need to keep to the pre-defined constants. If this doesn't work then your Java Card application doesn't support this key size and you're basically out of luck for that key size.

Comment: The error was the exponent I was using to recreate the key. But, I changed the code to create the key inside the card and send it to the PC. It worked well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the length of Modulus is not equal to 2048bits, the ILLEGAL_USE maybe thrown.

Answer (score -1):

Your algo is wrong here

```
cipherId = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_RSA_PKCS1, false);
```

Please try

```
cipherId = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_RSA_NOPAD, false);
```

Comment: This is the type of algorithm, either way I can use both.